# vscode warn when I use vue3 <script setup>

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, vite

A warning appeared but not tips, how to fix?

I use the vite init project with vue-ts template

only warn but not tips when i hover,and build also success

[image: 1C4D22B8-4D5D-47B3-B289-6D6E1A5F86DE.jpg]

my eslintrc :

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 13,
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["vue", "@typescript-eslint"],
  rules: {
    // indent: ["error", 4],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
    semi: ["error", "always"],
  },
};
```

[image: image.png]

I have  installed  Vue Language Features (Volar)

Comment: you are running a new program and just after you got this error? How you got it ? the explanation is not clear.

Comment: By "not tips", do you mean no *error message*? What do you see when you hover over the red squiggly line?

Comment: yes, when I hover ，there no tips, only a red wavy line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#how-to-use-a-custom-parser

You have

```js
parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 13,
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    sourceType: "module",
  }
```

can you try

```js
parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 13,
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
```

You can also check out this repo which has ESLint with TypeScript and Vue set up already and compare your config to the one there: https://github.com/sethidden/vue3-eslint-stylelint-demo